# Printing random number in Java

Tags: java, encryption

So, I'm a bit of a noob in the world of coding, and I'm working on a Caesar cipher that works under the premise of having a random number being the key.

```
package cryptography;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class Caesar_Cipher {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
        Random generator = new Random();
        int x = generator.nextInt();
        String input;
        char[] letters;

        System.out.println ("Input original message.");
        input = scanner.nextLine();

        letters = input.toCharArray();

        for (int index = 0; index < letters.length; index++) {

            letters[index] += x;

        }

        System.out.println ("The key is: " + x + ". \n"); //Here's the problem
        System.out.print ("Your encrypted message: ");
        System.out.println (letters);

    }

}
```

The problem is that I have no clue how to print the same number as was used in the encryption.

Comment: What is the problem there? It should print the same number as used in the "encryption"

Comment: It doesn't. I tried to use the same number to see if I get the same message, but I didn't.

Comment: Are you trying to understand how decrypt the message, or truly just print the key?  To decrypt, you have to perform the OPPOSITE of the operation that you used to encrypt (with this encrypt anyway)!

Comment: Just print the key. I know how to decrypt it, I have a separate program for it.

Comment: I don't understand. Nothing ever changes the value of `x` in the code you posted after it was assigned an initial random value. How is that not the number you expect?

Comment: It printed a different message than what I wrote.

Comment: WHAT printed a different message than what you wrote?  where is the decrypt code?

Comment: It's basically just this without x as the key and the number as it instead. The += becomes a -=, too.

Answer (score 1):

SIR, you're confusing everyone with your question. You wanted to print out what you typed in, but is asking a totally different thing about the random key and stuff.

You can't print an array of char[] as is using `System.out.println(the_char_array);`, either you convert it first to a readable (i.e toString() is properly implemented) object (such as a String), or use a loop to print out each letter one by one.

Edit: It became clear to me what you want to happen with this comment:

> It printed a different message than what I wrote.